# set umask for sshfs-mounted filesystem

Tags: permissions, filesystems, mount, sshfs, umask

I have a remote sshfs filesystem mounted on `/mnt/data`. Following is the relevant line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
www-data@192.168.1.10:/var/www/ /mnt/data       fuse.sshfs   rw,noauto,nodev,nosuid,noexec,_netdev,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=martin,gid=martin    0   0
```

The files in `/var/www/` on the remote system are owned by user `www-data`, but I am using `uid=martin,gid=martin` to map the ownership on the mounted filesystem to uid 1000.

When I cd to `/mnt/data/` as martin, I have the correct file permissions/ownership, but I need to change the umask.

On the remote filesytem, the user `www-data` has umask `0027`. On my local filesystem, the user `martin` has umask `0077`. I want to keep the umask `0077` on my local files, but use `0027` on the sshfs mounted files (ie all files in /mnt/data/).

**Is this even possible ?**

I have tried setting acl permissions on the whole directory on the remote filesystem:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rx  /var/www/
setfacl -d -m o::--- /var/www/
```

but this has no effect on the sshfs mounted share.

Answer (score 6):

`sshfs` is using `sftp` under the hood and the `umask` for creation new files is handled by the remote `sftp-server`. You can set `umask` as an argument to the `sftp-server` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, such as

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 027     # Debian/Ubuntu
```

or

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -u 027 # RHEL/Fedora
```

or

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server -u 027         # Arch
```

The umask settings and extended ACL are not transferred through the SFTP protocol as implemented by openssh. Also note that there is no "`umask` on files", but `umask` is always associated with running process creating the files.

Comment: I have added `-u 027` to the line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and restarted `ssh`, but it does not seem to have any effect. Files are created still with the old umask `0077`

Comment: Did you restart the ssh(d) service on the server? Or do you use also `ForceCommand` option there?

Comment: yes, I have restarted ssh on the server `service ssh restart`. What do you mean by `ForceCommand` option? I have no `ForceCommand` in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Also make sure that you reconnect your `sshfs` mount. Otherwise I don't see any reason why this should not work. Only possibility would be that the files are sent from your host with already stripped permissions (for example`600`) and then the `umask` on the server does not have any effect. You should be able to see that when running the server in debug mode (`LogLevel DEBUG3`). Lines `request $filename: open flags $flags` should tell what flags are send.

Comment: the `-o umask=027` switch to sshfs (when used in `/etc/fstab`) only affects how existing files are shown on the mounted filesystem. But it does not represent the actual permissions on the remote server, nor does it affect true permissions (on the remote server) of newly created files.

Comment: For Arch Linux you can use `Subsystem      sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server -u 027` or `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 027`

Comment: YES! "... and the umask for creation new files is handled by the remote sftp-server." This was the missing link. This solves the challenge to get proper access on the remote machine by other users, too. Thank you!