# Default permissions on new folder

Tags: permissions

When a user creates a folder over SFTP it gets permissions of

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

I need it to have

```
drwxrw-r--
```

I know i can change the permissions with chmod but it would save me lots of time and effort if the folder could be created with the correct permissions from the start. Is there a way to change the default permissions for when a specific user creates a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directories are typically created with all permission bits set (see for example [`mkdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html), when the mode isn’t specified explicitly), [except those masked by the current `umask`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287281/86440), so you can set that for the user you’re interested in;

```
umask 013
```

will produce the result you’re after under such circumstances.

For your specific `sftp` requirements, see [Proper way to set the umask for SFTP transactions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393919/86440)

Other approaches can be used if your file system supports ACLs and you don’t need to limit this to a single user; see [How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1314/86440) for details.

Comment: … except for `install -d` which defaults to 00755.  (-:

Comment: Thanks for this, i want this change only to apply to a single user - not sure if this makes a different but the user can only access the server over sftp - when they created a folder is where i saw this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, this is specific to a user, the `umask` is set per process. I’ll have to check whether this is usable over sftp; please add that requirement to the question.

Comment: Im sure this is for a lack of knowledge on my part but i am not clear how to set the umask on my specific user

Comment: See the link I added in my answer.